# ASP.net MVC 5 loading HTML.Partial from controller instead of loading on cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

new to MVC so here goes.

I am currently loading up **HTML.Partial** on my **Index.cshtml page** like so:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Switchb/editPerson.cshtml")
```

However, I am in need of customizing that in the controller depending on the current users **category number**.

So as an example, if the user has a category of 3 then I would need to do this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Switchb/3.cshtml")
```

Is there any type of call in the **"code behind"** in the controller that I can use in order to do that? Or would I just need to place the code within the cshtml page and pass its category number via the controller over to the cshtml page?

Comment: You can make ajax call to load the data from client , when you have the category number.

Comment: Use `@Html.Action()` to call a server method that returns your partial

Answer (score 3):

You can render a partial view from a controller action. You can pass the view name as string.

```
public ActionResult Switchb(string categoryNumber) {
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel { CategoryNubmer = categoryNumber };
    // additional processing, backend calls, formatting ....
    return PartialView(categoryNumber, viewModel);
}
```

To call this action from View:

```
@{
    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new {
        categoryNumber= "3",
    });
    Html.RenderAction("Switchb", "MyController", routeValues);
}
```

Comment: But I'm not using any viewModels. I'm only using Model/View/Control.

Comment: Well, if you don't need any data in the view "3.cshtml" (i.e. static content), you do not need to pass a viewmodel. In this case the action only does a kind of redirect, and the solution of Peter Morris will be simplier.

Comment: @StealthRT: I think you're confused as to the relationship of a "view model" to MVC. Your "model" is whatever is fed to the view, and the idea of creating view models is to create classes that actually serve the needs of your view, rather than using something generic and often inappropriate, such as an entity class (which is what I think you think is the "model"). For a more complete explanation, see my post, Entities Are Not Models (https://cpratt.co/entities-are-not-models/).

Answer (score 1):

Determine the category in the controller (via url parameter, from a database, or whatever) and then set that value as a property on your view's Model. Then in your line of code you can do this

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Switchb/" + Model.Category + ".cshtml");`

Comment: But I'm not using any viewModels. I'm only using Model/View/Control.

Comment: Then create a view model for that view